# How to fix NoSuchElementException in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking to scrape as much data as I can regarding EV companies on Crunchbase, starting with Name, Industry, and HQ Location. Except every time, I try I run into a problem: first-I ran into NoSuchElementException, so I added some WebDriverWait code, then I ran into a "NameError: name 'By' is not defined", fixed that; and for some reason now I'm getting "NoSuchElementException" again . How do I fix this? any help is appreciated ! :)

```
###Import Selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

#set driver path
PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organizations/field/organization.companies/categories/electric-vehicle")

print(driver.title)
#wait to find element
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
          (By.XPATH, ('/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/search/page-layout/div/div/form/div[2]/results/div/div/div[3]/sheet-grid/div/div/grid-body/div/grid-row[1]/grid-cell[2]/div/field-formatter/identifier-formatter/a/div/div')
        )))


companies = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ng-star-inserted')
#iterate through companies for data
for company in companies:
    name = company.find_element_by_xpath('./html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/search/page-layout/div/div/form/div[2]/results/div/div/div[3]/sheet-grid/div/div/grid-body/div/grid-row[1]/grid-cell[2]/div/field-formatter/identifier-formatter/a/div/div').text
    industry = company.find_element_by_xpath('./html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/search/page-layout/div/div/form/div[2]/results/div/div/div[3]/sheet-grid/div/div/grid-body/div/grid-row[1]/grid-cell[3]/div/field-formatter/identifier-multi-formatter').text
    hq = company.find_element_by_xpath('./html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/search/page-layout/div/div/form/div[2]/results/div/div/div[3]/sheet-grid/div/div/grid-body/div/grid-row[1]/grid-cell[4]/div/field-formatter/identifier-multi-formatter/span').text
    print(name,industry,hq)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with below code :

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/search/organizations/field/organization.companies/categories/electric-vehicle")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
print(driver.title)

name = []
industry = []
hq = []
industry_counter = 1
hq_counter = 2
companies = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.identifier-label")
for company in companies:
    name.append(company.text)
    industry.append(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//div[contains(text(), 'Industries')]/ancestor::grid-header/following-sibling::grid-body/descendant::grid-row/grid-cell/descendant::identifier-multi-formatter)[{industry_counter}]"))).text)
    hq.append(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//div[contains(text(), 'Industries')]/ancestor::grid-header/following-sibling::grid-body/descendant::grid-row/grid-cell/descendant::identifier-multi-formatter)[{hq_counter}]"))).text)
    industry_counter = industry_counter + 2
    hq_counter = hq_counter  + 2

print(name)
print(industry)
print(hq)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output :**

```
Query Builder | Organizations | Crunchbase
['Lucid Motors', 'ChargePoint', 'NIO', 'Lordstown Motors', 'Tesla', 'Bird', 'Helbiz', 'Joby Aviation', 'TIER Mobility', 'Solid Power', 'VOI Technology', 'Volta Trucks', 'Xpeng Motors', 'Ideanomics', 'Lightyear']
['Automotive, Autonomous Vehicles, Electric Vehicle,', 'Automotive, Electric Vehicle, Manufacturing,', 'Automotive, Autonomous Vehicles, Electric Vehicle,,,', 'Automotive, Electric Vehicle, Industrial,', 'Automotive, Autonomous Vehicles, Electric Vehicle,', 'Electric Vehicle, Mobile, Mobile Apps,,', 'Electric Vehicle, Last Mile Transportation,', 'Aerospace, Air Transportation, Electric Vehicle,', 'Electric Vehicle, GreenTech, Last Mile Transportation,', 'Battery, Electric Vehicle, Energy, Energy Storage,', 'Electric Vehicle, Public Transportation,,', 'Automotive, Electric Vehicle, Last Mile Transportation,', 'Automotive, Autonomous Vehicles, Electric Vehicle,', 'Digital Marketing, Electric Vehicle, Financial Services,,', 'Automotive, Electric Vehicle, Energy, Manufacturing,']
['Newark, California, United States', 'Campbell, California, United States', 'Shanghai, Shanghai, China', 'Warren, Ohio, United States', 'Palo Alto, California, United States', 'Santa Monica, California, United States', 'New York, New York, United States', 'Santa Cruz, California, United States', 'Berlin, Berlin, Germany', 'Louisville, Colorado, United States', 'Stockholm, Stockholms Lan, Sweden', 'Sigtuna, Stockholms Lan, Sweden', 'Guangzhou, Guangdong, China', 'New York, New York, United States', 'Helmond, Noord-Brabant, The Netherlands']
```